# Add watermark to all PDF pages

Tags: command-line, pdf, pdftk

Please tell me how to use the command line correctly in this case.
And so the task, there are a lot of pdf files on all pages of these files I need to add a watermark.
I made watermark in pdf and it works.
I have already used pdftk, but only for one file, that is, when we open the terminal in the directory and enter - "pdftk original.pdf multistamp link.pdf output final.pdf"
Everything works fine for one file.
PdfChain - I also tried it, there is also no way to process several files at a time from a folder.

But how to do with it if I have 1000 files in the directory, what should I do in this case?
What should the command look like in the terminal?
I did not find anything in the manual.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the following command

```
for i in *.pdf; do pdftk "$i" multistamp link.pdf output "${i%.pdf}"-final.pdf; done
```

It takes each pdf file (let's say, `filename.pdf`), and applies the stamp, and saves it to `filename-final.pdf`.